# How can I use a custom table as a node type?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I am reasonably new to Drupal, I have written a couple of basic modules by following the excellent videos from buildamodule.com

Now I need to somehow integrate an existing table into a drupal site.  I would like this table to be accessable as a content / node type to the rest of the drupal system.  I do not want to add this as a content type to drupal and use the table per field system drupal has as I already have the table structure and need to be able to update the data in this table from an external source.

I tried creating a new content type in a module and was able to create a schema using the schema module.  However when i use  `field_create_field` and `field_create_instance` I end up with a seperate set of fields.

How do I create a new content type in a module that can use an existing table for its data ( even if I need to provide access functions in my module)?

Is there a good tutorial somewhere that someone knows of?

Comment: Have a look at the [Ubercart module](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) and the way they integrated the product content type with their product table. Might give you some ideas.

Comment: Can you provide more details about "integrate an existing table"? Anything else apart from query / display those date in your Drupal site?

Answer (score 1):

While you're making work for yourself using a custom table and not the Field API, you can use your own table with

- [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) ( load data from custom table into node )
- [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) ( insert record in custom table )
- [hook_node_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) ( update record in custom table )
- [hook_node_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7) ( delete record from custom table )

You'll probably also need

- [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

if you want to add form elements to the node form.

Keep in mind the Field API will do that all for you though if using standard fields.

Comment: My problem is I want to be able to manipulate the db table from outside drupal which is more combersome with 10 tables - 1 for each field

Comment: You can use the Drupal API from outside Drupal with a standalone PHP script. e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5015816/583715